# How to fix display problem when I use QGraphicsView and QGraphicsEffect together in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicseffect

I have a problem when use `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsBlurEffect` in my project. When I put them together, my program does not work normally. I wrote a tiny program to reproduce this problem.

The `Widget` class is inherited from `QGraphicsView`.

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    this->setScene(scene);

    label = new QLabel;
    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap("../partly_cloudy.png").scaledToWidth(200);
    label->setPixmap(pixmap);
    label->setGeometry(100,100, pixmap.width(), pixmap.height());
    label->setStyleSheet("border:3px;border-color: rgb(255, 100, 0); border-style:solid;");

    /* ********image won't show when adding following comment code********
    QGraphicsBlurEffect *blur = new QGraphicsBlurEffect;
    blur->setBlurRadius(10);
    label->setGraphicsEffect(blur);
    ******* */

    QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxyWidget = new QGraphicsProxyWidget;
    proxyWidget->setWidget(label);
    proxyWidget->setPos(10,10);

    scene->addItem(proxyWidget);
}
```

and `main.cpp` is as follows.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

This is a screenshot when `QGraphicsBlurEffect` is not used.

[image: Without effect]

However, this is a screenshot when `QLabel` uses `setGraphicsEffect()` to bind blur effect.

[image: With effect]

To solve this problem, I tried to use a `QWidget` to wrap `QLabel`. When I did this, `QLabel` was rendered. However, it seems to be bounded by a rectangle area.

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    this->setScene(scene);

    /* ********/
    container = new QWidget;
    container->setStyleSheet("border:3px;border-color: blue; border-style:solid;");
    /******** */

    label = new QLabel(container);
    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap("../partly_cloudy.png").scaledToWidth(200);
    label->setPixmap(pixmap);
    label->setGeometry(100,100, pixmap.width(), pixmap.height());
    label->setStyleSheet("border:3px;border-color: red; border-style:solid;");

    QGraphicsBlurEffect *blur = new QGraphicsBlurEffect;
    blur->setBlurRadius(10);
    label->setGraphicsEffect(blur);

    QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxyWidget = new QGraphicsProxyWidget;
    proxyWidget->setWidget(container);
    proxyWidget->setPos(80,80);

    qDebug() << proxyWidget->boundingRect();

    scene->addItem(proxyWidget);
    this->setSceneRect(0,0,640,480);
}
```

The screenshot of the result is.

[image: Result of the program]

I tried to set `proxyWidget` position to {0,0}, and it works normally. it seems that the position of effect rectangle will not influenced by `proxyWidget` position.

By the way, the version of Qt is 5.14.2.

I've searched for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: did you try to apply the effect on the QGraphicsProxyWidget?

Comment: As you said, I tried to apply it to the proxyWidget, and it worked well. However, the reason why i use QGraphicsView is to realize the effect of switching between two widgets. In one of widgets, QGraphicsBlurEffect is used to beautify the UI. So I am looking for some way that can achieve this.